# Error in colSums(mat) : 'x' must be numeric GOchord plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was trying to plot the gene chord diagram, but I got an error" Error in colSums(mat) : 'x' must be numeric". I prepared the file myself, I submitted the target genes on Metascape, all these genes were enriched and picked from 6 signal pathways clusters. And then I downloaded the metascape_results file, added the logFC of each gene by hand. At last, copy "Gene Symbol", "GO term" and "logFC" to generate a new csv file.

The codes I used as follows:

```
library(GOplot)
library(circlize)
chord <- read.csv("GOchord_test.csv",header = T,sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
head(chord)

##gene_id    heart development phosphorylation vasculature development
## PTK2                  0               1                       1
## GNA13                 0               0                       1
## LEPR                  0               0                       1
## APOE                  0               0                       1
## CXCR4                 0               0                       1
## RECK                  0               0                       1
##       blood vessel development tissue morphogenesis cell adhesion
## PTK2                         1                    0             0
## GNA13                        1                    0             0
## LEPR                         1                    0             0
## APOE                         1                    0             0
## CXCR4                        1                    0             0
## RECK                         1                    0             0
##       plasma membrane      logFC
## PTK2                1 -0.6527904
## GNA13               1  0.3711599
## LEPR                1  2.6539788
## APOE                1  0.8698346
## CXCR4               1 -2.5647537
## RECK                1  3.6926860
6 rows | 1-5 of 22 columns
GOChord(chord, space = 0.02, gene.order = 'logFC', gene.space = 0.25, gene.size = 5)
Error in colSums(mat) : 'x' must be numeric`
```

Comment: You can create a reproduceable example using ```dput(chord)```. Is there a column that we cannot see called ```mat```? If so, is it as easy as ```chord$mat <- as.numeric(chord$mat)```?

Comment: @nateroe  Hi! Thank you for your help! I add the code "chord <- dput(chord)" , it seemed working better now, but still got the same error "Error in colSums(mat) : 'x' must be numeric". at the last step, I got some information like this " structure(list(gene_id = c("VPS4B", "HLA-E", .....WP179.Cell.cycle = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,.....logFC = c(0.49757581, -0.565940791, 0.529128705,.....class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-262L)). I think it is almost there, could you give me more advice for this issue? thank you!

Comment: ```dput()``` will allow us to see your data so that we can help more easily. Enter ```dput(chord)``` and paste the result into your question. It is the ```structure(list(....))``` code that you started to enter above. That will make your question reproduceable, and it will be much easier to answer your question.